# What does ‘they belonged’ mean in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> A second later, a gigantic pair of wheels and headlights had screeched to a halt exactly where Harry had just been lying. **They belonged**, as Harry saw when he raised his head, to a triple-decker, violently purple bus, which had appeared out of thin air. Gold lettering over the windscreen spelled The Knight Bus.

I have looked up the meaning of ‘belong to’ in some dictionaries, but still don’t understand. Is there any meaning of ‘belong to’ other than when you say you are a member of certain group or team?

Comment: They belonged ... to a ... bus. That is, they are a part of the bus.

Comment: Rowling is deliberately being a bit "quirky". We wouldn't normally talk about something like wheels *belonging* to a vehicle unless they'd somehow become separated. As in a garage / workshop, where everything has been dismantled and spread around, and it might be necessary to specifically identify *these* wheels as "belonging" to this vehicle, whereas *those* wheels *belong to / are associated with* some other vehicle. Rowling is implying that the wheels have somehow become separated from the bus, ***for dramatic effect*** (emphasising that Harry noticed the wheels much more than the bus).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you! It is so helpful. With your explanation these sentences sound more dramatic and exciting. Thank you.

Comment: You've certainly chosen a good book for learning English! Rowling has an excellent ear for language, *and* she can tell a good tale. Enjoy!

Comment: ...note that Rowling doesn't "talk down" to her readers (although she's primarily writing for *children*, she doesn't artificially restrict her vocabulary and syntax in case her readers might be unfamiliar with a usage). But they are still essentially "books for children". If you're still into fantasy novels and want to move on to something a little bit more "advanced" in the future, look out for Mervyn Peake's *Gormenghast* trilogy.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - I find the use of 'belonged" quite natural. Harry's view is restricted because he is lying flat. He sees the wheels first, and it is when he raises his head that he finds out to which vehicle they are attached. You could say this about boot-clad feet that (it transpired) belonged to a policeman, or paws that belonged to a dog.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: By "quite natural", are you implying that you don't recognise the *not in its normal position, physically separated from its "owner"* allusions I set out? Each to their own, but personally I'm in no doubt that this implication is indeed present, ***and*** was intended by Rowling. ***And*** that it's in the interests of the OP here to be aware of that.

Comment: (Your "it transpired" caveat simply implies that something *might as well have been dislocated*, because initially it wasn't possible to see that the wheels and bus were in fact connected. That's the whole *point* of the usage here! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you! I added Gormenghast to my reading list! Once I’ve finished reading HP I would try it!